# What is the difference between reftex-citation and org-reftex-citation?

Tags: org-mode

What is the difference between `reftex-citation` and `org-reftex-citation`?

And where can I find the documentation for `org-reftex-citation` referenced in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3381/6890)?

[1] [Emacs manual: Creating citations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Options-_002d-Creating-Citations.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the documentation for `org-reftex-citation` by doing:

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-reftex-citation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

In fact, you can use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> (`describe-function`) to look up documentation for any [command or function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3556/504) that is available in your Emacs installation.

As for the difference between `reftex-citation` and `org-reftex-citation`: The former allows you to quickly insert citations into LaTeX documents, while the latter enables you to do the same for `org-mode` files. They are related in the sense that after identifying the correct `.bib` file to use for the current file, `org-reftex-citation` calls `reftex-citation` to insert a citation at point.

#### Bonus: More on getting help from Emacs itself

In addition to `describe-function` there are a number of commands that you can use to ask Emacs about itself. Some of the most useful ones are:

- `describe-variable` (<kbd>C-h v</kbd>)
- `describe-key` (<kbd>C-h k</kbd>)
- `describe-key-briefly` (<kbd>C-h c</kbd>)
- `describe-mode` (<kbd>C-h m</kbd>)
- `describe-package` (<kbd>C-h P</kbd>)

Comment: "The former allows you to quickly insert citations into LaTeX documents, while the latter enables you to do the same for org-mode files." - Which is to say that the former gives you something like `\cite{author99}` and the latter gives you something like `[[cite:author99]]`. Even in an org-mode file, if you mainly export from org-mode to LaTeX, `reftex-citation` may still be what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers! I will try it out in the next days and will vote up as soon as I have enough points on this StackExchange site

Comment: @BrianZ `org-reftex-citation` produces the same format as `reftex-citation` on my machine (`\cite{author99}`). I have zero customizations regarding `reftex` in my configuration.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Then I guess the basic difference is in how they look for the bibliography file?

Comment: @BrianZ Yes, I think that's it. `org-reftex-citation` looks for a `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY:` line while `reftex-citation` collects relevant info from the `\bibliography` command.