# org-agenda-files not getting set in .emacs

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda

I have multiple org files in my Dropbox directory. I wanted to add all of them into my org-agenda. So as normally prescribed I used `org-agenda-files`. Infact I'm adding the the part of my .emacs that corresponds to org-mode setup below

```
;; ############  ORG-MODE  ####################
;; ## To enable shift - arrow mode for navigation (does not work in CUA mode)
(require 'org)
(setq org-support-shift-select t)
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "STARTED(s)" "ISSUE(p)" "INPUTNEEDED(i)" "VERIFY(v)" "|" "SCOPECHANGE(c)" "DONE(d)" "DELEGATED(o)")))
;; To hightlight code blocks ** SO Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642888/syntax-highlighting-within-begin-src-block-in-emacs-orgmode-not-working **
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(setq org-directory "~/orgFiles")
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull  "~/orgFiles/from-mobile.org")
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Apps/mobileorg")
;; ## Make RefTeX work in org-mode
;; ## https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/loading-bibtex-file-in-org-mode-file
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f"))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c [") 'org-reftex-citation)

(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Professional"))
```

I also verified that the variable is getting set by Performing `M-x customize-variable org-agenda-files`. Now when I perform `M-x org-agenda t`. I get the following output

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with `N r': (0)[ALL]
```

I have numerous TODO in the org-files in the folder and I dont know why they dont get reported in the `org-agenda`

Comment: I wonder if you need to escape the space in the pathnames. So just do `(setq org-directory "/Users/kw1/Dropbox\ (Personal)/orgFiles")`, etc.

Comment: The problem is I want the org files to be found recursively and I think org-agenda-files cannot do that. Do you know of a way to find the org files recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Apparently the `org-agenda-files` can only add the org files that are immediately in the directory path. It cannot recursively add org files in the subdirectories, which was how my org files were stored. I solved it using the recipe as described in the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384907/1652217). The full elisp code is attached below

```
;; ## Search org files recursively and add it to agenda
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384516/how-to-make-all-org-files-under-a-folder-added-in-agenda-list-automatically
;; recursively find .org files in provided directory
;; modified from an Emacs Lisp Intro example
(defun sa-find-org-file-recursively (&optional directory filext)
  "Return .org and .org_archive files recursively from DIRECTORY.
If FILEXT is provided, return files with extension FILEXT instead."
  (interactive "DDirectory: ")
  (let* (org-file-list
     (case-fold-search t)         ; filesystems are case sensitive
     (file-name-regex "^[^.#].*") ; exclude dot, autosave, and backup files
     (filext (or filext "org$\\\|org_archive"))
     (fileregex (format "%s\\.\\(%s$\\)" file-name-regex filext))
     (cur-dir-list (directory-files directory t file-name-regex)))
    ;; loop over directory listing
    (dolist (file-or-dir cur-dir-list org-file-list) ; returns org-file-list
      (cond
       ((file-regular-p file-or-dir) ; regular files
    (if (string-match fileregex file-or-dir) ; org files
        (add-to-list 'org-file-list file-or-dir)))
       ((file-directory-p file-or-dir)
    (dolist (org-file (sa-find-org-file-recursively file-or-dir filext)
              org-file-list) ; add files found to result
      (add-to-list 'org-file-list org-file)))))))

(setq org-agenda-files
      (append (sa-find-org-file-recursively "~/Professional")))

(setq org-agenda-text-search-extra-files
      (append (sa-find-org-file-recursively "~/Professional" "txt")
              (sa-find-org-file-recursively "~/Professional" "tex")))
```