# Cannot cite anything

Tags: org-mode, org-export, bibtex

I've seen this question: [Loading bibtex file in org-mode file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/loading-bibtex-file-in-org-mode-file) as well as this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114864/how-to-get-bibtex-to-work-with-org-mode-latex-export

I've tried adding `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: sources plain` to my Org document, this allowed `org-reflex-cite` to find the reference I'm citing, but the generated `tex` file has no mentions of bibliography.  If I add LaTeX headers such as:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliographystyle{plain}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{sources}
```

They are copied as is into the document, but that has no effect.

Org mode always generates an empty `bbl` file.

I've tried all of these commands for generating `tex` / `pdf` files:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
        ;; ("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f")
        '("texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f"
          "bibtex %b" "texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f"
          "texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f")

        ;; '("latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f"))
```

with the result being the same.

Below is the `sources.bib` I'm using:

```
                  @Preamble{"\def\germ{\frak} \def\scr{\cal}
 \ifx\documentclass\undefinedcs
      \def\bf{\fam\bffam\tenbf}\def\rm{\fam0\tenrm}\fi
                          % f**k-amstex!
 \def\defaultdefine#1#2{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
 \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}\fi}
 \defaultdefine{Bbb}{\bf}   \defaultdefine{frak}{\bf}
  \defaultdefine{=}{\B}   % doublef**k-amstex!!
  \defaultdefine{mathfrak}{\frak}
       \defaultdefine{mathbb}{\bf}
       \defaultdefine{mathcal}{\cal}
      \defaultdefine{beth}{BETH}\defaultdefine{cal}{\bf}
     \def\bbfI{{\Bbb I}}   \def\mbox{\hbox}  \def\text{\hbox}
   \def\om{\omega}    \def\Cal#1{{\bf #1}} \def\pcf{pcf}
        \defaultdefine{cf}{cf}
    \defaultdefine{reals}{{\Bbb R}} \defaultdefine{real}{{\Bbb R}}
   \def\restriction{{|}}  \def\club{CLUB}
   \def\w{\omega} \def\exist{\exists}
   \def\se{{\germ se}}     \def\bb{{\bf b}}
   \def\equivalence{\equiv}
   \let\lt<  \let\gt>
           "}

@article{Secil,
author = {Mustafa Seçil, Obuz, Funda, Altay, Canan, Ömür Gencel, Igci, Enis, et al.},
title = {{The role of dynamic subtraction MRI in detection of hepatocellular carcinoma}},
journal = {Diagnostic and Interventional Radiology; Ankara},
volume = {14, Iss. 4}
pages = {200--204},
year = {Dec 2008},
}
```

I copied the preamble from an example here: http://shelah.logic.at/eindex.html (I don't really know how bibtex works, and was hoping to skip learning this part for now...)

Comment: I voted to close as unclear, as based on a comment by OP, the problem wasn't with Emacs at all, but rather a badly formatted bib file.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with this command?. As far I as I remember you need to run texi2dvi 3 times. Besides as far as I know you need to put `\bibliography{sources}` in the body where you want the bibliography not in the preamble.

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process (quote ("texi2dvi --pdf --build=local --verbose     --batch %f"
                    "bibtex %b"
                    "texi2dvi --pdf  --verbose --batch %f"
                    "texi2dvi --pdf  --verbose --batch %f")))
```

You can try running the generated tex file to see if it runs.

Comment: I also tried `biblatex` rather than `bibtex`, but the culprit wasn't either. The problem was that my `sources.bib` file had minor problem with its format: the commas in the authors, which I had to replace with `and`.  This made `bibtex` generate empty `sources.bbl`...